# Can't connect to Oracle DB from webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, oracle, code-access-security

I'm using VS2010 to develop a web service that has to connect to an Oracle database that resides on a remote server. The service is being deployed to the VS Development IIS that VS2010 starts up by default.

The web service is working until I try to open an Oracle connection.  The database user id and pswd is specified in the connection string (e.g.; integrated security is NOT being used.)

The error message I get is the following:

> ((System.Security.SecurityException)$exception).Message
>
> Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OraclePermission, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Code Access Security issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163700.aspx).

[MVP Nicole Calinoiu says](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlnetfx/thread/92fbdad6-8064-4a22-8285-685665fe3d96):

> You need to deploy your assembly at the UNSAFE CAS permission level.

If you don't have .NET 4 installed, you can [use the .NET Framework Config Tool (mscorcfg.msc)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to modify permissions.

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid, how do I do that?

The assembly I'm creating does not appear in the assembly cache. I'm guessing that's because it's only deployed when I go into debug mode.

What permissions should I apply?

Thank you!